# Node.js encrypt a string into alphanumerical

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am currently using NPM module crypto-js to encrypt strings. The codes are the following:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("hello", "secrete_key").toString()
```

This yields to an encrypted string of: `U2FsdGVkX1/G276++MaPasgSVxcPUgP72A1wMaB8aAM=`

Notice that in the encrypted string, there are special symbols such as `/` `+` and `=`. These generated special symbols cause a problem in my app. Is there a way that I can encrypt a string into only alphanumericals? I like the way crypto-js is doing, since it is simple. I only need to feed in the string, and a password hash. If crypto-js cannot, what other modules can achieve this in a simple and straight-forward way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CryptoJS also includes utilities for encoding/decoding so you can convert your encrypted string to a URL-safe format. See the [CryptoJS docs](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) for more info.

For example:

```js
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("hello", "secrete_key").toString()
var encoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

console.log(encrypted)
console.log(encoded)

var decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encoded).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decoded, "secrete_key").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(decoded)
console.log(decrypted)
```